# How do I stop screen from clobbering my titles?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I am using `bash` and GNU `screen` on centos7. I notice that if I ssh to another server, change the title (via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and log out of the server that my new title gets overwritten by `USER@HOST:~`. How can I stop it from doing this?

I've looked into [dynamic titles](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Dynamic-Titles.html) and determined that's what's at play, but I'm unsure of how to disable that feature...

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532203/135943

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As documented in the man page, `screen` looks for a null title-escape-sequence. `bash` sends this sequence via the [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) environment variable (for example, mine defaults to `printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`.

To disable this feature for a particular window, I just run `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` from that window. Of course, one could just add this to their `~/.bashrc` or to a specific environment file to make it more persistent.

Comment: If `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is empty, check `$PS1`.

Answer (score 0):

On the screen mailing list, Steve Ross wrote:

> I just realized that, although one approach is to unset the
>   PROMPT_COMMAND variable, another approach is to use the "screen"
>   command of "defdynamictitle off" in my "~/.screenrc" file.  With this
>   setting, the content of the PROMPT_COMMAND variable does not have an
>   effect when opening new screen-window. For a previously opened
>   screen-window, the related "screen" command of "dynamictitle off" lets
>   you to turn off dynamic changes to the title of the screen-window.