# Turn off GNU screen dynamic window titling for entire screen session

Tags: gnu-screen, prompt, window-title

I found:

- [GNU Screen window rename nuisance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206100/135943)

However, none of the answers there solve my problem and my situation is slightly different from the linked question.

I work in a large infrastructure where I might log into any of hundreds of hosts in a given day.  I don't have the authority to manage the default `PROMPT_COMMAND` on all of these servers.

I've read through the man page section about naming windows (`LESS='+/^TITLES' man screen`) and I don't see any solution therein to my problem.

**How can I cause my windows in screen to KEEP the titles I set** (with Ctrl-A A) **regardless of the settings on servers I log into from my screen session?**

(Example use case: I might have a window titled "db-hosts" where I can log into a random sampling of DB hosts to check them, logging out from any given one when I am done checking it and logging into a different one.)

Comment: can you edit the .bashrc (or whatever) and check the login's source IP address (e.g. with something like `who -m | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'` - but note that who's output varies considerably between versions/inplementations), and then unset PROMPT_COMMAND if it's you?

Comment: @cas not feasible to do on hundreds (actually thousands) of servers, most of which I may never log into more than once.  I just want `screen` to ignore the titles set from the command line, and only take them from my `Ctrl-A-A` sequences.  Although if there is a way within `screen` to have the effect of a `.bashrc` on each server when I log into it, that would suffice.

Comment: you could hack the `screen` source.  or get into the habit of pasting your own 'PROMPT_COMMAND='...'` command into each shell when you log in (`unset` by itself won't do,  you have to undo the damage caused by any existing PROMPT_COMMAND setting)

Comment: @cas, if there is some way to save the window name in a variable in `screen` and then reset the window name with some keybinding, so the workflow would be: log in, type keybinding to unset `PROMPT_COMMAND`, type keybinding (same for all windows!) to restore the saved window title—that would be a good workaround.  :)  I intend to open a bounty for this question once I can, by the way; it's a real productivity issue for me at work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232655/can-i-get-terminal-title-or-otherwise-restore-old-one

Comment: on second thoughts, that won't work - you'd need to modify the .bashrc on each remote server.     i feel your pain, though - i hate having .bashrc login scripts change my title or add garish colours to my prompts.  I nuke the defaults in /etc/skel and so on with extreme prejudice on my own machines, and grit my teeth and bear it on machines I can't "fix".

Comment: @cas, I've opened a bug report (feature request): https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?56674

Comment: You could setting `export TERM=dumb` within your screen on the assumption that this environment variable with be transferred over to the remote host when you use your login method.

Comment: @cas in case you missed it, answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [bug report I posted](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?56674) was answered almost immediately [with a comment](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?56674#comment1) that this feature was added in a newer version of `screen`:

> Since v.4.5.0 there is
>
> ```
> defdynamictitle [on|off]
> ```
>
> for global setting and
>
> ```
> dynamictitle  [on|off]
> ```
>
> for per window settings.